PPL types in the UK
Can someone explain the different PPL type for a plane? I see UK-PPL, CCA-PPL, EASA-PPL, Part-FCL.
My intentions is I will be moving to America (SF) in about 1-2 years time and want to transfer it over. Are there any difference in which one I get.
Is just as costly to learn there compared to the UK (I am in Southampton), so might as well get started.

When transferring to the United States, you'll need to work with the FAA (Federal Aviation Administration). The good news is that foreign pilot licenses can be converted to a US Private Pilot License through a process called "validation" or "conversion." EASA-PPL or UK-PPL are generally the most straightforward to convert to a US license

UK-PPL - Valid within the UK and recognized internationally, follows UK-specific aviation regulations
EASA-PPL - Standardized across European Union countries, follows common European aviation standards

I recommend starting your training in the UK, as you'll be more familiar with the local conditions and can complete your license before moving. The skills and knowledge are largely transferable, and you'll save time by not starting from scratch in the US.
